# Absolute Continuous Function is bounded?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, absolute-continuity

Suppose $v:[a,b]\to R$ is absolutely continuous ($W^{1,1}$) and its derivative $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Is the function v then bounded ?

My reasoning so far:
f is continuous $\Rightarrow$ v'=f is bounded $\Rightarrow$  with x AC $\Rightarrow$ x is Lipschitz on a compact set

Is my reasoning correct. If not what property might I be missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even easier:

Note that every absolute continuous function is continuous. Since the domain is compact, then by Extreme value theorem it admits a minimum point and a maximum point. Hence it is bounded.

Comment: Thanks :).May I have a follow up question. If I have no information about compactness, what would be required to achieve boundedness ?

Comment: Well, in that case it is not enough. Pick $f(x)=x^3$. It is smooth and with smooth derivative, but it is unbounded.

Comment: Thats a good counter example.  Yet I would have at least boundedness because of the absolute continuity right ? (That is my last question, I am grateful to you for answering).

Comment: I would not say so. Absolute continuity of a function does not imply boundedness at all. Do not worry about the questions! If we can, we are here to help :)

Comment: Ah then I was probably misled by the bounded variation property.  Thanks again you helped me alot :)

Comment: Happy to help! :)